# Force close in my tabhost

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

Why is there an error in my code? I'm calling two classes in same package. one is the "BatteryInformation.java" which extends Activity and its function is to get the Battery Info, the next one is "TaskKiller.java" which extends Activity also and its function is to kill running application. This two class has no error and i run it without this UI and it works well. can you please help me?

```
public class BatteryDoctorSaverActivity extends Activity {
    TabHost tabHost;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

        // Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BatteryInformation.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Battery Information").setIndicator("")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TaskKiller.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Task Killer").setIndicator("TaskKiller")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }
}
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
01-23 10:30:55.949: D/AndroidRuntime(12278): Shutting down VM
01-23 10:30:55.949: W/dalvikvm(12278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=batterydoctorsaver.thesis.BatteryInformation }
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at batterydoctorsaver.thesis.BatteryDoctorSaverActivity$1.onClick(BatteryDoctorSaverActivity.java:22)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-23 10:30:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(12278):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can anyone help me with this. I'm stack with this UI for almost 2days. i didn't know what to do. please help me. THANKS FOR THE HELP :)

@Lucifer Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="batterydoctorsaver.thesis"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".BatteryDoctorSaverActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".BatteryInformation" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- <activity android:name = ".BatteryInformation"/> -->

</manifest>
```

@Lucifer here sir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="batterydoctorsaver.thesis"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".BatteryDoctorSaverActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BatteryInformation" />
        <activity android:name=".TaskKiller" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is my code in may BatterDoctorSaverActivity.java:

```
package batterydoctorsaver.thesis;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import batterydoctorsaver.thesis.BatteryInformation;
import batterydoctorsaver.thesis.TaskKiller;

public class BatteryDoctorSaverActivity extends TabActivity {
    TabHost tabHost;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.setup();
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator("Battery Information")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, BatteryInformation.class)));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Task Killer")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, TaskKiller.class)));

        // tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Updates").setContent(
        // new Intent(this, DownloadList.class)));

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you declare the `BatteryInformation` Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: ah nope. 
but is just like this <activity android:name = ".BatteryInformation"/> and i will put it in androidmanifest?

Comment: Yes, you have to declare any and all **Activities** in your manifest before you can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your activity to your AndroidManifest.xml file. All the activity must have an entry to that file.

remove this lines from your code,

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".BatteryInformation" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

instead use following lines.

```
<activity> android:name=.BatteryInformation />
```

Comment: I still got the error. I put the activity in AndroidManifest.xml file but still it has an error.

Comment: can you please upload your AndroidManifest.xml's code in question ?

Comment: how can i do that? ask question again? is that what you mean sir?

Comment: you can call me Lucifer, Please find an "edit" link below your question. click on edit & edit your question by editing the code

Comment: @Lucifer i put my AndroidManifest.xml file in my question already. can you please tell me what my error is? thank you

Comment: ok, TaskKiller is a normal class or activity ? if it is normal class then convert it to activity & add its entry to manifest.xml

Comment: its activity sir. but when i put the id in setContent(R.id.tab1); of the first tab it has no error but there is no content in the tab just an interface.

Comment: no matter, but if it is activity it must have an entry line in menifest.xml file

Comment: yes sir i put it now in the manifest.xml file but still i got the error.

Comment: sir i already uploaded my update manifest and also the BatteryDoctorSaver.java that holds the TabHost/TabActivity

Comment: Please visit this link, it will be very useful for you http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/tablayouttabhost-tutorial-for-android-reusing-layout/

Comment: sir i already visited this site but still i got the error i don't know why maybe in the class that i call or the tab.xml that i make for the tabhost.